# Issue with variable inside a binary match

Tags: elixir

Given this code:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def my_func(<< part::binary-size(size), rest::binary >>, size) do
    IO.puts(part)
  end

  def my_func_2(size, << part::binary-size(size), rest::binary >>) do
    IO.puts(part)
  end

  def my_func_3(size, << part::binary-size(size-1), rest::binary >>) do
    IO.puts(part)
  end
end
```

The module won't compile. If I comment out all functions but one, I get different errors:

1. Compiling with `my_func/1` gives me this error:

   ```
   warning: variable "size" does not exist and is being expanded to "size()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
     my_script.exs:2

   ** (CompileError) my_script.exs:2: size in bitstring expects an integer or a variable as argument, got: size()
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:52: :elixir_bitstring.expand_bit_info/5
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:29: :elixir_bitstring.expand_bitstr/4
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:10: :elixir_bitstring.expand/3
       (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
   ```
2. Compiling with `my_func_2/1` gives me another error:

   ```
   ** (CompileError) my_script.exs:6: variable size@1 is unbound
       (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
       (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
   ```
3. Compiling with `my_func_3/1` gives me a different error:

   ```
   ** (CompileError) my_script.exs:10: size in bitstring expects an integer or a variable as argument, got: :erlang.-(size, 1)
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:52: :elixir_bitstring.expand_bit_info/5
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:29: :elixir_bitstring.expand_bitstr/4
       (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:10: :elixir_bitstring.expand/3
       (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
       (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
   ```

**Can someone explain all errors to me? What is happening at the erlang compiler level and why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang and Elixir fooled us to believe that we can do nested pattern matching on every datastructure, but binaries are an exception. [Here](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html#id66823) you can read that

> Binary patterns cannot be nested (...) segments have the following general syntax:
>
> `Value:Size/TypeSpecifierList`
>
> When matching `Value`, value must be either a variable or an integer, or a floating point literal. Expressions are not allowed.
>
> Size must be an integer literal, or a previously bound variable. The following is not allowed:
>
> ```
> foo(N, <<X:N,T/binary>>) ->
>   {X,T}.
> ```
>
> The two occurrences of N are not related. The compiler will complain that the N in the size field is unbound.
>
> The correct way to write this example is as follows:
>
> ```
> foo(N, Bin) ->
>   <<X:N,T/binary>> = Bin,
>   {X,T}.
> ```

This is also true for Elixir.

So in `my_func` compile doesn't try to look in the function head after the first parameter and says that there is no variable called `size`. It figures that it might be a function and then compiler blows up with an error saying that `size in bitstring expects an integer or a variable as argument`.

In `my_func_2` things get tricky, because the variable is there in the first argument, but it is not yet bound. This is exactly the case from Erlang documenation above. You can't pattern match on the size. It must be previously bound variable. The name `size@1` hints you that compiler doesn't treat the two as the same variable. They have different names internally.

In `my_func_3` compiler sees that there is a subtraction so it doesn't bother to check for variables and immediately reports that you can't use expressions inside binary pattern match.

The correct way to work around this limitation is also in the quoted part.

Comment: Are Binaries the only exception for nested pattern matching?

Comment: I believe yes. There are only couple of other native collection datastructures: lists, tuples (records) and maps. All of them support nested pattern matching.